# Custom function taking string as input which breaks a math problem into smaller bits and adds them to an array

Tags: python, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

I have recently started learning python and am trying to build a simple function to break up a math problem into smaller parts. For example if the problem is (1+2)+(2+4) it would break it up and store it in an array: ["(1+2)", "+", "(2+4)"].
Below ill post the code i have so far.

code:

```
def crush(string):
    crushed_string = []
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        current_problem = ""
        if string[i] == "(":
            for x in range(i, len(string)):
                if string[x] == ")":
                    for y in range(i, x+1):
                        current_problem += string[y]
                    print(current_problem)


string = "(1+2)+(3+4)"
crush(string)
```

I am printing current_problem to the terminal instead of adding it to an array just for testing but the output i am getting doesn't make sense to me...
the output:
`(1+2)`
`(1+2)(1+2)+(3+4)`
`(3+4)`

I'm not looking for a code dump but rather to understand what is happening and why so i can improve and not just copy paste. If anyone could please explain why this is the output i am getting i would be really grateful.

note: I know i haven't added the + between the brackets yet but I've ran into this problem before I've gotten to that and would like to first understand what is happening before moving on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform math operations into a string, the best solution is to use `regular expressions` like this. To learn more about them, please visit the official Python documentation about the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library :

```
import re

s = "(1+2)+(3+4)"
print(re.findall('[+-/*//()]|\d+',s))
```

**Output**
As you can see, it breaks down the string to an elemental level, not only reducing parenthesis:

```
['(', '1', '+', '2', ')', '+', '(', '3', '+', '4', ')']
```

Comment: Probably a stupid question but is this not the same as just creating an array where each element is the next character in the string? I need to return a list which holds the seperate problems. Eg: ["(1+2)", "+" , "(1+2)"] so i can calculate the seperate problems before in this case adding them together. Is this an efficient way to go about this or is there a better way to calculate math problems containing parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [@Cardstdani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591980/14541164) method, but here is a complex maze of if else statement which resembles your desired result.

```
def crush(string):
    crushed_string = []
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        current_problem = ""
        if string[i] == "(":
            for x in range(i, len(string)):
                if string[x] == ")":
                    for y in range(i, x+1):
                        current_problem += string[y]
                    crushed_string.append(current_problem)
                    i = x+1
                    break

    return crushed_string

string = "(1+2)+(3+4)"
print(crush(string))
```

output:

```
['(1+2)', '(3+4)']
```